# Javascript function returning undefined when passing key value

Tags: javascript, object, key, parameter-passing, undefined

Console.log returns:

key1
undefined

I expect to see:

key1
["first", "second"]

---

```
var testfunc = function(a) {
    var matrix = {
        key1: ["first", "second"],
        key2: ["third", "fourth"]
    };

    var b = matrix.a;

    console.log(a);

    console.log(b);
}

var otherfunc = function() {
    return "key1";
}

testfunc(otherfunc());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) to access a dynamic property.

So it should be: `matrix[a]` instead of `matrix.a` which is undefined.

```js
var testfunc = function(a) {
    var matrix = {
        key1: ["first", "second"],
        key2: ["third", "fourth"]
    };

    var b = matrix[a];

    console.log(a);

    console.log(b);
}

var otherfunc = function() {
    return "key1";
}

testfunc(otherfunc());
```

---

```js
const obj = {
  x: 'x',
  y: 'y'
};

const x = 'y';
console.log(obj.x);
console.log(obj[x]);
```